# Is it possible for a single Java Virtual Machine to have different id's

Tags: jvm, pid, jvm-hotspot

We're running several JBoss instances with HotSpot 1.5.22 and today I found a JVM which has two different vmid's. This is what I'm seeing:

```
$./jinfo -flags 13278
Attaching to process ID 13278, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 1.5.0_22-b03
[flags for jboss_node_b1]

$./jinfo -flags 20569
Attaching to process ID 20569, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 1.5.0_22-b03
[flags for jboss_node_b1]

$./jinfo -flags 13255
Attaching to process ID 13255, please wait...
Error attaching to process: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach to the process
```

Now, if I run "ps -ef | grep jboss_node_b1" I have only one process for this node running with PID 13278. Actually, it would be impossible for two instances of the same node to be running since one of them would crash.

This is what jps is reporting:

```
$./jps
13278 -- process information unavailable
20569 -- process information unavailable
13255 -- process information unavailable
26716 Jps
[several other jboss jvms]
```

So I have this:

- jboss_node_a1: pid 13255, vmid 13255 but I can't monitor it
- jboss_node_a2: pid 13278, vimd 13278 & 20569

How could this be? Could this be a bug in the 1.5.22 monitoring tools?

Regards